# Where is the changelog?

Tags: node-config

I got a project which need to go from `config` v1.30.0 to v2.0.1 if I do the upgrade. I searched the repository for a Changelog either on the README or as a separated file, also searched in the releases part on github, checked the Wiki and read the "Future Compatibility" and the "Ample Warning", however none of that assures me that things will not break after the update. Also no reference to the work "break" on a `git log` over the repo.

Is there another place I should look to find the changes, I'd really like the package to have a better way of notifying changes so one can safely upgrade.

Another question: could this be considered a feature request, so I can file an issue on the repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This package comes with a `History.md` file, at the root of the sources, that acts as a changelog.

Here it is: https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/blob/master/History.md